# reactJs + typescript + debounce - cannot import debounce properly

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have problem with importing `debounce` library properli into `react +  typescript` project.

I have done:

1. `npm install debounce --save`
2. `typings install dt~debounce --save --global`
3. in my file, import debounce as: `import debounce from 'debounce';`
4. use debounce like: `debounce(function(){ console.log('testtt'); })();`

With these code my code compillation is passing, but when I'm trying to run webside i get error:

`Uncaught TypeError: debounce_1.default is not a function`

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that `lodash` library has the `debounce` function and a typings for typescript.

It works like this:

```
import _ = require('lodash');

...

class SearchControl extends React.Component<ISearchControlProps, ISearchControlState> {
    private debouncedLoadSuggestions;
    constructor(props: any) {
        ...
        this.debouncedLoadSuggestions = _.debounce(this.fetchSuggestions, 500);
    }

    fetchSuggestions = (value: string) => {
        ...
    };

    onSuggestionsFetchRequested = ({value}) => {
        this.debouncedLoadSuggestions(value);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue as well. It seems the typings for `debounce` are just wrong, perhaps for an outdated non-module version of the library. I'm not inclined to bring in all of `lodash` just for this function so for anyone in the future, these typings work for me:

```
declare module "debounce" {
  function debounce<F extends Function>(func: F, wait?: number, immediate?: boolean): F;
  namespace debounce {}
  export = debounce;
}
```

Example:

```
import * as debounce from "debounce";

document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", debounce((e: MouseEvent) => console.log("moved"), 500));
```

Comment: This does not work for me, on the latest Typescript I get: Module '/node_modules/@types/debounce/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannotbe imported using this construct.

Comment: @RobertMassaioli I'm actually still using this in TS 2.9, but some things have changed that might lead to a better way... it looks like currently the `@types` definitions are written with `export =`, which you can't import using wildcard or default. What I posted here a couple years is essentially [this workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5073) merging the export with a namespace so it can be imported using wildcard. You would uninstall `@types` and use this in its place. (Your error is still pointing to `@types`.) *However* you should also look into `esModuleInterop`...